# How can I compare the directry lists inside directories?

Tags: total-commander

I have 2 directories, A and B. In A, I have subdirectories 1, 2, 3, 4 while in B I have 1 and 3. How can I highlight 2 and 4 easily?
The contents of the subdirectories are the same, respectively, so I just want to compare the names.

Mark -> Compare Directories only compare files, but not directories.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can use other tools, but there is another way to compare directories (unless you don't mind using a command line).

In **macOS** you can simply type this command in the terminal:

```bash
    $ diff A/ B/
    Common subdirectories: A/1 and B/1
    Only in A/: 2
    Common subdirectories: A/3 and B/3
    Only in A/: 4
```

or

```
$ diff -rq A B
Only in A/: 2
Only in A/: 4

-r recursively compares any subdirectories
-q shows only differences without any details
```

For **Windows**

- preinstalled `comp` command. Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/comp)
- preinstalled `fc` command. Here is the [link](https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html)
- also you can download [gnuwin32](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm) which provides `diff` command and you can use it in almost the same way as described above.

Hope it helps somehow.